# Is a local directory that has rwx permissions for all users vulnerable to attacks?

Tags: permissions, calibre

I'm just learning Unix and noticed my Calibre Library is set to `drwxrwxrwx`.
I read that changing it's permissions will cause errors. I always add reputable files to the database, but it seems like a bad idea to have a database with open permissions.
Do I have any basis to worry about?

Comment: I don't know what Calibre is, but the accessibility of a directory also depends on the permissions of the directories above it, of its parent directories.

Comment: it's complex to answer that, it depend of so much parameter and how much people want to hack you. Having a folder with rwx is not bad nor good, it really depend. In this case I would say it's kinda OK

Comment: If my answer  solved your problem, please [accept it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the checkmark next to it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Being world-writable implies that any local user or process could fill up that partition with large files or large numbers of files, making that partition unusable for anything/anyone else. If Calibre's Library sits on its own partition, the damage is limited; you have only one root partition, the scope of the damage increases.

I don't use Calibre, but if it was my system, I'd start by removing the world-writable bits.